# How to hide material bottom app bar on scroll but the fab stays

Tags: flutter, android-bottomappbar

I have a material bottom app bar widget with a fab search button attached to it in the center. I want it to scroll down (the fab stays) when I scroll the screen.

I want to implement this scrolling behavior.
https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#behavior

Comment: Hello. Please add the code you've tried and what exactly isn't working for you. Alternatively a quick Google search shows this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353640/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-in-flutter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Bottom Navigation bar on Scroll in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353640/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-in-flutter)

Comment: That's not exactly the same question. He didn't ask about fab to stay. If you have the answer then please tell me.