# Hide bottom navigation bar on scroll down and vice versa

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: screenshot]

I have a list in the body and bottom navigation bar. I want to hide bottom navigation bar with a slide down animation when the posts list is scrolled down and visible with a slide up animation when scrolled up. How to do it?

Comment: Check out -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71538425/14247462

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Screenshot (Null safe + Optimized)

[image]

---

#### Code:

```dart
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  late final ScrollListener _model;
  late final ScrollController _controller;
  final double _bottomNavBarHeight = 56;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _model = ScrollListener.initialise(_controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _model,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $i')),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: _model.bottom,
                child: _bottomNavBar,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _bottomNavBar {
    return SizedBox(
      height: _bottomNavBarHeight,
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.call), label: 'Call'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.message), label: 'Message'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollListener extends ChangeNotifier {
  double bottom = 0;
  double _last = 0;

  ScrollListener.initialise(ScrollController controller, [double height = 56]) {
    controller.addListener(() {
      final current = controller.offset;
      bottom += _last - current;
      if (bottom <= -height) bottom = -height;
      if (bottom >= 0) bottom = 0;
      _last = current;
      if (bottom <= 0 && bottom >= -height) notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: very nice exapmle . great

Answer (score 25):

While Naveen's solution works perfectly, I didn't like the idea of using `setState` to handle the visibility of the navbar. Every time the user would change scroll direction, the entire homepage including the appbar and body would rebuild which can be an expensive operation. I created a separate class to handle the visibility that uses a `ValueNotifier` to track the current hidden status.

```
class HideNavbar {
  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  final ValueNotifier<bool> visible = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);

  HideNavbar() {
    visible.value = true;
    controller.addListener(
      () {
        if (controller.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.reverse) {
          if (visible.value) {
            visible.value = false;
          }
        }

        if (controller.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.forward) {
          if (!visible.value) {
            visible.value = true;
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    visible.dispose();
  }
}
```

Now all you do is create a final instance of `HideNavbar` in your HomePage widget.

```
final HideNavbar hiding = HideNavbar();
```

Now pass the instance's `ScrollController` to the `ListView` or `CustomScrollView` body of your `Scaffold`.

```
body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: hiding.controller,
          ...
```

Then surround your `bottomNavigationBar` with a `ValueListenableBuilder` that takes the `ValueNotifier` from the `HideNavbar` instance and then set the height property of the bottomNavigationBar to be either 0 or any other value depending on the status of the `ValueNotifier`.

```
bottomNavigationBar: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: hiding.visible,
        builder: (context, bool value, child) => AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          height: value ? kBottomNavigationBarHeight : 0.0,
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              BottomNavigationBar(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                fixedColor: Colors.white,
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                items: const [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    title: Text('Home'),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                    title: Text('Offers'),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                    title: Text('Account'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

This approaches keeps avoids countless rebuilds and doesn't require any external libraries. You can also implement this as a stream-based approach but that would require another library such as `dart:async` and would not be changing anything. Make sure to call the dispose function of `HideNavbar` inside `HomePage`'s dispose function to clear all resources used.

Answer (score 14):

Working code with `BottomNavigationBar`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController _hideBottomNavController;

  bool _isVisible;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isVisible = true;
    _hideBottomNavController = ScrollController();
    _hideBottomNavController.addListener(
      () {
        if (_hideBottomNavController.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.reverse) {
          if (_isVisible)
            setState(() {
              _isVisible = false;
            });
        }
        if (_hideBottomNavController.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.forward) {
          if (!_isVisible)
            setState(() {
              _isVisible = true;
            });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _hideBottomNavController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverPadding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              sliver: SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) => _getItem(context),
                  childCount: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        height: _isVisible ? 56.0 : 0.0,
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              fixedColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text('Home'),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard),
                  title: Text('Offers'),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                  title: Text('Account'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getItem(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Item',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Working Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDAKn.gif)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for now! At least until the Flutter team makes an upgrade

Comment: wrap container helped to avoid overflow issues