# BottomNavigationBar showing overflowing warning on hide

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

I am hiding my `bottomnavigationbar` upon scroll. The hiding works as expected but the navigation bar thinks it is an issue and it's showing render overflowing warning message. How do I fix it?

I am using a **scopedModel** to listen to a `boolean` on scroll. `mainModel` is my `scopedModel`class.
`mainModel.getShowAppBar` is just a `boolean` which i have set inside the scopedModel class.

Current behavior of the app that showcase the problem:

[image: BottomNavigatorBar Overflow]

and this is my code implementation:

```
  List <BottomNavigationBarItem> _showIconsOrNot(){
     var iconList = [
     BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Container(
          child: new Icon(Icons.list)
        ),
       title: new Text("Forums"),
     ),
     BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Container(
           child: new Icon(Icons.home)
        ),
        title: new Text("Home"),
     ),
     BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Container(
          child: new Icon(Icons.person)
        ),
        title: new Text("Profile")
     ),
     BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Container(
          child: new Icon(Icons.notifications)
        ),
        title: new Text("Notifications")
    )
   ];

return iconList;
}



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new ScopedModel<MainModel>(
    model: mainModel,
    child: new Scaffold(
      body: new ScopedModelDescendant<AppModel>(
          builder: (context, child, model){
            return SomeListView(model);
          }
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:
      new ScopedModelDescendant<AppModel>(
          builder: (context, child, model){
            return AnimatedContainer(
                curve: Curves.bounceOut,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                height: mainModel.getShowAppBar ? 60.0 : 0.0,
                child: BottomNavigationBar(
                  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                  currentIndex: currentIndex,
                  iconSize: mainModel.getShowAppBar ? 24.0 : 0.0,
                  selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
                  unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
                  items: _showIconsOrNot
              )
            );
          }
      )
  )
);

}
```

I expect the overflowing warning message to disappear. Hiding animation works flawlessly as expected.

Comment: You may want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439481/6618622)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Thanks, but it seems to be using a custom bottomnavbar. I need to use the flutter bottomnavbar as I am also having pageviews to navigate around each tab.

Comment: Thanks all for editing the post. I have insufficient reputation to post image

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `BottomNavigationBar` with `Wrap` widget. Set `AnimatedContainer`s height to 56.0.

```
.......
return AnimatedContainer(
  curve: Curves.bounceOut,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  height: mainModel.getShowAppBar ? 56.0 : 0.0,
  child:  Wrap(
    children: <Widget>[
      BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        iconSize: mainModel.getShowAppBar ? 24.0 : 0.0,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        items: _showIconsOrNot
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
.......
```

Need full implementation? Goto [Hide bottom navigation bar on scroll down and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414268/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-down-and-vice-versa)