# Hide BottomNavigationBar while scrolling up

Tags: flutter

Using BottomNavigationBar in the 3rd item I have 1 `ListView.builder`,

how to hide `BottomNavigationBar` while scrolling up

Code provided:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Go Bid"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  body: tabs[_currentIndex],
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text("Status"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            title: Text("Search"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414268/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-down-and-vice-versa/58766865#58766865

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide bottom navigation bar on scroll down and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414268/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-down-and-vice-versa)