# Flutter- How to pass scrollcontroller controller to other widgets in flutter to hide bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

e.g if if using BottomNavaigationBar and below are 4 widgets

```
List<Widget> pageList = <Widget>[
Widget1(),
Widget2(),
Widget3(),
Widget4(),
```

];

each has its Listview.builder to show items, so now when we scroll i need to pass controller between bottomnavigation bar and other widgets to  hide the bottom navigation bar on scroll. Please help i couldnt find any solution, every code example i get they have bottom navigation bar and list view in same widget and controller is passed to hide bar.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414268/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-down-and-vice-versa

Comment: Abhijit thank you so much for responding , the link has bottom bar and list view in same widget, how to listen if the list view is in other sub widget, can we pass controller or listen to scroll notification, if listen i need to know how to listen for the scroll in bottom bar.

Comment: I am not sure about this.let consider this scenario, if the listview is same design in every bottombar screen then you could dynamically change data with only one listview widget instead of multiple listview ,if not then you have to create scrollcontroller for every listview then repeat the process like in the answer, i am not sure it is best idea and also try using same controller for other listview check it is working