# How to hide a bottom navigation when scrolling down in pageview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-pageview

I got stuck when i wanna implement auto hide a bottom navigation when scrolling down and show a bottom navigation when scrolling up. I already search how to implement auto hide, but the main problem came from the pageview, i cant put the page controller & scroll controller in the same widget. I've also tried wrap it using another widget and put the scroll controller, but it became blank. What the best way to implement this thing? This is the code that i use.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
              child: PageView(
            controller: pageController,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                selectedPage = index;
              });
            },
            children: [
              Center(
                child: HomePage(),
              ),
              Center(
                child: CategoryPage(),
              ),
              Center(
                child: EventPage(),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: CustomBottomNavBar(
              selectedIndex: selectedPage,
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedPage = index;
                });
                pageController.jumpToPage(selectedPage);
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You should use scrollbar controller and follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353640/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-in-flutter)

Comment: After i wrap the children inside pageview using listview and then put the scroll controller inside listview, it works.Thanks.