# How to hide bottomNavigationBar, while the page is been scrolling up?

Tags: flutter

I've created a bottom `NavigationBar` like below, but I have difficulties hiding it while the page is scrolling up, and showing it again if the page is scrolling down.

I have a list of blog posts in the body and bottom navigation bar. I want to hide the bottom navigation bar when the posts list is scrolled up and make it visible with a slide-down animation. How to do this?

Hide BottomNavigationBar while scrolling up. Here is my code for BottomNavigationBar:

```dart
      class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
          bool isSignedIn= false;
          int _CurrentIndex=0;
          int _agentCurrentIndex=0;
          String owneruerID;
          String uploadusertypes;
          List<Widget>_children;
          List<Widget>_agentchildren;
    
          void initState(){
            super.initState();
            GetData();
            uploadusertypes= widget.UserType;
            owneruerID = widget.userID;
            _children=[
              TimeLinePage(tuserID:owneruerID,tUserType:uploadusertypes),
              ManinClass(), //search(),
              UploadPage(UserSID:owneruerID,uploadusertypes:uploadusertypes),
              NotificationsPage(),
              ProfilePage(userProfileID:owneruerID),
            ];
            
              if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null){
                setState(() {
                  isSignedIn= true;
                });
              }else{
                setState(() {
                  isSignedIn= false;
                   });
              }
          }

----------

           @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          return buildagentScreen();
        }else
         {
          return buildHomeScreen();
        }
      }

----------

    Scaffold buildHomeScreen(){
          return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              body: _children[_CurrentIndex],
              bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
                currentIndex: _CurrentIndex,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                onTap: onTabchangePage,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                inactiveColor: Colors.white,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.home),title: Text('home'),),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.search)),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.photo_camera,size: 40,)),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.notifications)),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_sharp)),
                ],
              ),
            );
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Bottom Navigation bar on Scroll in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353640/hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-scroll-in-flutter)

Comment: No! Can you show me a hint on my code how I implement it?