# When using Flutter Visibility widget, can the change in visibility be animated?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a column holding a number of containers. The top and bottom containers are always shown, but the ones between sit inside a Visibility widget. If the user taps the screen, the middle containers are made visible, and then are made invisible again on the next tap. So essentially, the column expands and contracts each time it's tapped.

I'd like the expansion and contraction to happen a bit more gracefully - currently it looks very harsh when the middle containers just suddenly appear. Is there any way of animating the way in which the containers are made visible and hidden? Or should I be looking at using a totally different Widget than Visibility?

Comment: You could wrap your desired containers in AnimatedSwitcher. First state could be render of your containers and after your user interaction you could just build empty SizedBox for example, AnimatedSwitcher should take care of the rest. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

Comment: Go take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493886/animated-opacity-and-hiding-the-widget-so-its-not-clickable

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far, check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: AnimatedSwitcher seems to handle this best, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an animated crossfade. Make the first child as SizedBox.shrink() and second child as the widget that you wish to display and it should be animating as expected.  And switch according to the requirement

```
bool _first = true;

AnimatedCrossFade(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
  firstChild: const SizedBox.shrink(),
  secondChild: const FlutterLogo(style: FlutterLogoStyle.stacked, size: 100.0),
  crossFadeState: _first ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
)
```

Alter the value of _first to true or false.

Comment: In a simple hello world test this solution looked best - it works well in terms of showing and hiding the panel, but unfortunately the layout within my container doesn't behave, the widgets jump around and it also causes a pixel overflow error when contracting. AnimatedSwitcher looks a little more graceful. Thanks for the suggestion.