# Flutter Floating Action Button with Dynamic Status

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button, appbar, flutter-appbar

Putting the finishing touches on my first Flutter mobile app.
Another important ToDo: My Floating Action Button appears in the Top App Bar for every page, but i would like its status to change (enabled / disabled) depending on the current page. Is this possible? if so, any tutorials, resources, reference material and / or code examples fit for a novice, would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cool, you can use [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html):

```
floatingActionButton: Visibility(
  child: FloatingActionButton(...),
  visible: false, // set it to false
)
```

Alternatively, you could use NotificationListener (more elegante but sophisticated).

Please check [this example from another publication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408336/13775248)

---

Edit: maybe controlling it directly in onPressed.
According to [official docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html):

*"If the onPressed callback is null, then the button will be disabled and by default will resemble a flat button in the disabledColor."*

```
FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: shouldButtonBeDisabled() ? null : () => whatToDoOnPressed,
      child: Text('blablabla')
    );
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! ..I will definitely use this one day. But not for this project, i don't think; as i want the button to remain visible, just not active. although your suggestion reminds me that visual cues are important to UI; if my button remains visible AND looks the same, it might be misconstrued as 'broken' on the disabled page. so i think a color and/or opacity change is something my solution needs as well, since it will remain visible. thanks

Comment: [EDIT] added one new suggestion. Check it out if it makes sense.

Comment: That might work. I mean, for an experienced programmer, probably definitely. Can I pull it off?.. that's another question entirely lol. But it seems simple enough, and only 3 lines.. that's a plus; i will give this a try asap.. stay tuned. Thanks!